# Ways to search for keywords on a website and select all to click if the word is hyperlinked or a button?

Tags: google-chrome

Perhaps much like a crtl + f functional but go a step further and have it click either each one at a time or if possible all at once?
I use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and run this script via the console.. probably want to disable your adblock..

```
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
setTimeout(function(){
$("a").each(function(){
$(this).click();
});

$(":button").each(function(){
$(this).click();
});
},2000);
```